# How do I reverse the Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, javascript-objects

How do i convert this:

```
{one:1,two:2,three:3,four:4}
```

to this:

```
{1:'one',2:'two',3:'tree',4:'four'}
```

I tried this :

```
Array.prototype.reverse.call({1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'tree',4:'four' length:5});
```

but this reverses the whole thing , which i dont want. Any one has any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to reverse the key value pairs.

```js
const obj = {one:1,two:2,three:3,four:4};

const reverseObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [value, key]));

console.log(reverseObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [for... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to do this, assigning the key at each property to the value in the resulting object.

```js
    
let o = {one:1,two:2,three:3,four:4};
let result = {};
for(let key in o) {
    result[o[key]] = key;
}
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could also use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) along with [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the result you wish:

```js
    
let o = {one:1,two:2,three:3,four:4};
let result = Object.entries(o).reduce((acc, [key,value]) => { 
    return { ...acc, [value]: key };
}, {});
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` to get key/value pairs into an array, and then `.reduce()` to construct a new object:

```
function invertObject(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce(function(newObj, pair) {
    newObj[pair[1]] = pair[0];
    return newObj;
  }, {});
}
```